# How to get offline-access with Google APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get `offline access` with Google APIs. I have to pull data from Google Calendar without having the user sign-in everytime.

I've added this to my Gemfile:

`gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.9'`

... And added this to my controller:

```
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
class Api::V1::CalendarAccountsController < Api::V1::BaseController
...
```

And in my action:

```
client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load(
  File.join(
    Rails.root,
    'config',
    'client_secrets.json')
  )

@auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization

@auth_client.update!(
    :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
    :redirect_uri => '/{callback URL}',

    :additional_parameters => {
      "access_type" => "offline",
      "include_granted_scopes" => "true"
    }
)
redirect_to @auth_client.authorization_uri.to_s
```

The problem is -- even though I'm specifying **"access_type"** as **"offline"**, I *still* don't get asked for offline-access privileges in the Google privileges list (I'm attaching a screenie below).

And here's the page Google loads (no offline-access):
[image: Google privileges list with no offline-access request]

And here's the URL that got generated when I called `@auth_client.authorization_uri.to_s`

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=[ID]&redirect_uri=[callback]&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&from_login=1&as=-23788065e9c098d9&pli=1&authuser=0

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using something like this:

```
client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
  client_id: your_client_id,
  client_secret: your_secret_id,
  authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  scope: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR_READONLY,
  redirect_uri: your_callback_url
})

client.update!(
  additional_parameters: {
    access_type: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent'
  }
)

redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s
```

Note that I am using a more recent version of the `google-api-client` gem, configured this way:

```
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.11', require: 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
```

This way Google will ask you for permission to interact with the Calendar API and correctly setting the `access_type` parameter to grant you offline access to the same APIs.

This approach will prompt the user for the authorization each time you call the code. If you want to prevent this, you have to change it this way:

```
client.update!(
  additional_parameters: {
    access_type: 'offline'
  }
)
```

If you have already authorized your app without the `access_type: 'offline'` parameter Google will grant you an authentication token without the offline permits. To reset this situation it is sufficient to go into [your Google profile permissions](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/permissions) and revoke the previous authorization for your application. Then try again.

(Note: the `signet` gem is a dependency of `googleauth`, which in turn is a dependency of `google-api-client`, so you get this code for free, without the need to add more gems to the `Gemfile`)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code. If your application needs offline access to a Google API, set the API client's access type to [offline](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline):

```
auth_client.update!(
  :additional_parameters => {"access_type" => "offline"}
)
```

> After a user grants offline access to the requested scopes, you can continue to use the API client to access Google APIs on the user's behalf when the user is offline. The client object will refresh the access token as needed.

Also use the Google client library, this will help you with refreshing an access token (offline access).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot -- I'm already adding the `access_type` parameter, but I still don't get the offline-access prompt on Google's log-in privileges page (it just asks for `read-only access to calendars`), and I don't get a `refresh_token` in the response either.